# Calling StoredProcedure from hibernate 3 resulting in (node to traverse cannot be null!)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Due to design constraint, I need to call a SP from hibernate using `entityManager.createQuery()` API. On calling this `entityManager.createQuery("call xxx(:caseId)")` result   in "`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!`". I have tried other options like  `entityManager.createQuery("call xxx(?1)")` etc..all resulting in same error. Anything I am missing? I know the error is very generic and related to some kind of syntax issue.

Can anybody let me know the correct syntax of calling SP using `createQuery`?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: What are the arguments you have pass to your SP and does your SP return any value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `org.hibernate.Session` for this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("CALL xxx(:caseId)").setString("caseId", valueForIt);
```

Note: if caseId is not a String use the appropriate set method.

Now you can do a `query.executeUpdate()`, or if you want something returned (a list for example) you can do a `query.list()`.